# How to determine the smallest natural number solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

```
y = a + bx where a and b are rational numbers.
```

I'm writing a program that uses equations which are of the same format as the equation above and I would like to find the most efficient way to get y and x.

A requirement for the solution is that both x and y are natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by multiplying by a natural number so as to clear the denominators of $a$ and $b$.  Then you can use results on linear diophantine equations to solve the resulting equation (if any natural number solutions exist).

See for example https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-diophantine-equations-one-equation/

Comment: I've been reading the link you sent and my only issue I see is that my function is of the form. y = a + bx which can be rewritten as y - bx = a. Functions in the link you sent are of the form y + bx = a. Would it matter that my b is an integer and not a natural number. If not then a little more help would be needed.

Comment: You should be able to get your equation into the form $mx + ny = p$ where $m,n,p$ are integers.  If you can then solve the corresponding equation with positive coefficients: $\lvert m\rvert x + \lvert n\rvert y = \lvert p\rvert$, you should be able to adjust the signs as needed to solve $mx+ny=p$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- Let $a=\dfrac{n_1}{d_1}$ and $b=\dfrac{n_2}{d_2}$ be both irreductible rationals.

It is necessary that $d_1$ divides $d_2$ in order to exist solutions. In fact
$$y=\dfrac{n_1}{d_1}+\dfrac{n_2}{d_2}x\iff d_1d_2y=d_2n_1+d_1n_2x\Rightarrow d_1|d_2n_1$$
Since $(n_1,d_1)=1$ one has $d_1|d_2$.

What follows?